# Structural stability of Morse-Smale diffeomorphisms

Tags: dynamical-systems, morse-theory

I'm trying to wrap my head around why Morse-Smale diffeomorphisms are structurally stable, using the real line as a toy example. Say $f$ is a Morse-Smale diffeomorphism. Proofs for more generalized versions use the fact that a map that is $C^1$-$\epsilon$ close to $f$ will have a unique hyperbolic fixed point for each fixed point of $f$. I'm having trouble understanding why this is the case, and I'm not sure how to prove it. I'm thinking of proving this by contradiction, like assume there exists a fixed point $p$ for a function $g$ that is $C^1$-$\epsilon$ close to $f$ that is not hyperbolic, but I'm stuck after writing the conditions $|f(p) - g(p)| = |f(p) - p| < \epsilon$ and $|f'(p) - g'(p)| = |f'(p) - 1| < \epsilon$.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Perhaps bite off a smaller piece first. Try $f(x)=2x$.

Comment: So the intuition is something like this? $f(x) = 2x$ has a fixed point at $x = 0$. A $g$ that is $\epsilon$ close to $f$ must map points into $B_\epsilon(0)$. I'm having trouble understanding why $g$ would need a fixed point in $B_\epsilon(0)$ though? If $g$ stays to the left of $f$ and above the line $y = x$, it won't have a fixed point here, let alone a hyperbolic one.